# Azure Service bus unique subscription name when scalling

Tags: c#, .net, azure, azureservicebus, azure-web-app-service

I have a scenario where I am topic and a subscription in the Azure Service Bus. The website creates a subscription to a topic. When an another instance of the website is create I want to create a new subscription with a unique name to the same topic. What will be the best approach. The website is hosted as a webapp in azure.

Comment: What is the use case? I wouldn't recommend doing that as you will have subscriptions that need to be cleaned up as website instances die.

Comment: Thanks Sean Feldman and JTaub, the scenario is when a message is published on a topic, the web app reads the message from the subscription and pushes it to the client using signalR. That is reason I thought of creating a subscription per instance because each instance is going to have it's own set of clients.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Azure Service Bus is a broker and your application should be a competing consumer (i.e. multiple instances feed of the same queue as those are just instances of the same web application that you scaled out). Saying that, sometimes you need to implement a mechanism like a callback, often used to communicate back to a specific instance of a webapp, all the way to the client side. For that, I'd suggest to look not into creating a subscription per webapp and not per instance (which could be done using [WEBSITE_INSTANCE_ID](http://blog.amitapple.com/post/2014/03/access-specific-instance/#.V3S7Pbh97s0) as a unique subscription ID). Just like John commented, the problem with subscription per instance is that when you scale in, the messages associated with the subscription for webapp instances that got de-provisioned will stay on the broker unhandled. Not to mention that constant scale-out/in will generate subscriptions that will be orphaned and not cleaned up.

Alternative would be to have a subscription per webapp and distribute those events to specific instances using something like [SignalR with a backplane](http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/performance/scaleout-in-signalr), which is specifically designed for that purpose. SignalR has several backplane implementations (Redis, Azure ServiceBus, SQL Server).

Comment: Thanks Sean Feldman and JTaub, the scenario is when a message is published on a topic, the web app reads the message from the subscription and pushes it to the client using signalR. That is reason I thought of creating a subscription per instance because each instance is going to have it's own set of clients.  But from what Sean has suggested, I can have just one subscription to the topic and use SignalR backplane to handle the scaling out scenario.

Comment: If I follow this route, the message should be made readable multiple times from the subscription. So the multiple instances can read the message and send it to client. So how do I set the count for it and when do I mark the message complete?

Comment: You only read the message once and broadcast with signalR using backplane. If successful, mark the ASB message as completed.